# Append some attributes in couchdb's userCtx

Tags: session, couchdb

As i know that couchdb supports _session to get a userCtx.

If i request it after login, then i would get like below.

> {"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"bob4","roles":["manager"]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["oauth","cookie","default"],"authenticated":"cookie"}}

Actually, this result is based on a _users's document.

I expect that i can get more information from a _users's document by _session.

Let me give you an example.

If i generate a document , a user information , with some attribute that is "e-mail" in _users.

And then, request _session after login.

I hope to get a result that includes an e-mail attribute , like below.

> {"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"bob4","e-mail":"joeh@gmail.com","roles":["manager"]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["oauth","cookie","default"],"authenticated":"cookie"}}

Is it possible to append some attributes to _session's result in couchdb?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You can request that information directly from the `_users` database. Also, I believe you get all the extended attributes when `userCtx` is passed to a `_list`/`_show` function.

Comment: 1. I think that to access on client side(app) directly is so dangerous. 
Because it means that anybody get the documents on _users db and passwords that are encoded by md5 will be exposure.

Comment: 2. So my solution was that 
- append an admin user on _security of _users db 
- arrange nginx in front of couchdb.
- append a header, authentication , on the nginx configuration to allow a PUT method only by admin 
- it means that the operations about _users will be allow by the PUT method only only only ( sign up )

Comment: 3. Accordingly, i am looking for solution to get _session's result that i want

Comment: 4. To be precise, i want to know that how the userCtx is generated and how modify it to get some information that is already appended a _users's document

Comment: 5. Most important thing is by _session call

Answer (score 0):

I inquired cloudant.com

His reply is here below. Thanks Rob O'Brien.

That is correct. CouchDB doesn’t currently support adding extra userCtx attributes the _session response data.